# Unable to "delete" the property of the object in mongoose Document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am unable to delete (in mongoose, its called unset) the field from the mongoose, but `$unset` is working. The following example will demonstrate my problem very well though.

Without `$unset`

```js
let user = await User.findById(user_id);
delete user.last_name;
await user.save();

user = await User.findById(user_id);
console.log(user.last_name); // Santiago
```

With `$unset`

```js
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, { $unset: { last_name: true } });

let user = await User.findById(user_id);
console.log(user.last_name); // undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `last_name` property of the `user` [Document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html) instance is a getter function that Mongoose adds from the model schema to make life easier.

The real document that you might be able to `delete` from is held in an internal variable.

You can set a field to `undefined` and mongoose will work it out for you:

```
user.last_name = undefined
await user.save()
```